# m smallest values of vector with size n (c++11)

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11

I need the average of the `nClose` smallest values (except the first zero) in a vector with `n` elements where we know that `nClose + 1 < n`, there are only non-negative numbers, and the vector contains at least one zero value. Furthermore, `nClose` will be a lot smaller than `n`, say that nClose will be around 10 and n will be around 500.

Normally I will use `min_element` to find the minimum, however this is useless here since I need several values. At the moment I use the following code

```
sort(diff.begin(), diff.end());
double sum = accumulate(diff.begin() + 1, diff.begin() + 1 + nClose, 0);
double avg = sum / nClose;
```

Due to the sort it runs in O(n log n) where we can do it in O(nClose*n) by just find the minimum and remove it, then repeat this for nClose times. Know one of you how to accomplish this with the algorithms of c++11?

Comment: `std::nth_element` maybe, but I'm not sure if mutation is a good idea.

Comment: @dyp exactly nth_element is the solution - complexity will be O(n)

Comment: @dyp What could go wrong with `std::nth_element(diff.begin(), diff.begin() + nClose + 1, diff.end());`?

Comment: @rickhg12hs mutation in this case means that the initial data input will be altered and the initial state of the array would not be achievable once `nth_element` is run. This is dyp's concern, but it might well be the case this is not an issue for the OP

Comment: If mutation is not allowed, you can use a priority queue whose size is capped at `nClose+1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`std::nth_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element) for that.

```
nth_element(diff.begin(),diff.begin()+nClose+1, diff.end());
double sum = accumulate(diff.begin(), diff.begin() + 1 + nClose, 0);
double avg = sum / nClose;
```

Regarding your remark about finding the minimum and removing it: This would probably be even less efficient than your current solution, as removing the nth element requires all elements after the nth position to be moved one position to the left, effectively turning your algorithm into something like O(nClose*n^2).

Also, while this should be a pretty efficient solution, I'd warn you against putting too much weight on algorithmic complexity, as the constants may actually play a much bigger role than any advantage in Big O notation.

Comment: nth_element proposed in the comment of the qustion is in better complexity and better for the task

Comment: @BorisStrandjev: My mistake, you are right of course, I changed the answer.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work. However we have to accumulate from `diff.begin()` now since it is not guaranteed that the first value is the zero. Furthermore, mutation is not a problem is this case since I just can make a copy of the original vector. However, is it also possible without mutating the data?

Comment: Thanks for removing the `+1`. You are definitely right about the time complexity, however I find them quit interesting and more important: I just try to find an algorithm for each 'simple' task like this since the algorithms are quite new for me.

Comment: @MichielUitHetBroek - it is possible if you use Heap - then the complexity will be `O(log(nClose) * n)`